# glBufferData keeps failing with GL_INVALID_ENUM even when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, c++, opengl-es, pinvoke

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code?

My call to `glBufferData` keeps failing and the error code is `GL_INVALID_ENUM`. But, my values are correct - I even tried hardcoding the values in directly (just in case). According to the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) this should work.

**EDIT**

I created a minimal - or as minimal as ANGLE + XAML + UWP can get - [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal). There are 5 main files where all the work happens:

- [MainPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/MainPage.xaml.cs)
   - the main coordinator that initializes ANGLE and starts a render loop
- [OpenGLES.cs](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/OpenGLES.cs) - the logic to initialize ANGLE context, display and surface
- [SimpleRenderer.cs](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/SimpleRenderer.cs) - the main rendering of the triangle
- [Egl.cs](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/Egl.cs) & [Gles.cs](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/Gles.cs) - the p/invoke methods

If you download and run the code, it should throw an exception after the [`glBufferData` on line 61](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/SimpleRenderer.cs#L62)

To toggle between a buffer-based array and the direct array, just change the line: [SimpleRenderer.cs#L31](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/SimpleRenderer.cs#L31)

**ORIGINAL**

For the life of me it appears to match the C++ code - which runs fine. I am using ANGLE on Windows UWP. (I have the full code [here](https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Example/blob/master/ManagedANGLE/SimpleRenderer.cs) if you need more context)

```cs
GLfloat[] vertexPositions = new[] {
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};

Gles.glGenBuffers(1, out GLuint mVertexPositionBuffer);
Gles.glBindBuffer(0x8892 /*Gles.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER*/, mVertexPositionBuffer);
var gcData = GCHandle.Alloc(vertexPositions, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try {
    var size = vertexPositions.Length * Marshal.SizeOf<GLfloat>();
    var data = gcData.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    Gles.glBufferData(0x8892 /*Gles.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER*/, size, data, 0x88E4 /*Gles.GL_STATIC_DRAW*/);
    // Gles.glGetError() == Gles.GL_INVALID_ENUM
} finally {
    gcData.Free();
}
```

My p/invoke layer `Gles` looks like this:

```cs
[DllImport(libGLESv2)]
public static extern void glGenBuffers(GLsizei n, out GLuint buffers);
[DllImport(libGLESv2)]
public static extern void glBindBuffer(GLenum target, GLuint buffer);
[DllImport(libGLESv2)]
public static extern void glBufferData(GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, IntPtr data, GLenum usage);
```

This is what my C++ code looks like:

```cpp
GLfloat vertexPositions[] = { ... };
glGenBuffers(1, &mVertexPositionBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mVertexPositionBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

I believe the rest of my setup/drawing code is correct because this draws just fine:

```cs
GLfloat[] vertexPositions = new[] {
     0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f
};
var gcData = GCHandle.Alloc(vertexPositions, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try {
    Gles.glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint)mPositionAttribLocation, 3, Gles.GL_FLOAT, Gles.GL_FALSE, 0, gcData.AddrOfPinnedObject());
} finally {
    gcData.Free();
}
Gles.glEnableVertexAttribArray((GLuint)mPositionAttribLocation);
Gles.glDrawArrays(Gles.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

Comment: An [mcve] would be nice.

Comment: My GitHub https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Example is almost minimal 3 buffers instead of the 1 here in the question, but I'll try get a single file version. GL is not the shortest code ever.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, this is very weird, that is why I started this question. I added a minimal sample that just tries to render a basic triangle: https://github.com/mattleibow/ANGLE-Minimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a 32 bit architecture e.g. [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86), then `GLsizeiptr` has to be a 32 bit datatype.

To solve the issue the type of the alias `GLsizeiptr` has to be `System.Int32`:

```
using GLsizeiptr = System.Int32;
```

If the type would be `System.Int64`, then the last paramters of

```
public static extern void glBufferData(
    GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, IntPtr data, GLenum usage);
```

would be misaligned.

This causes the `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error in [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBufferData.xhtml), because the value of the last parameter (`usage`) is not `GL_STREAM_DRAW`, `GL_STREAM_READ`... .

Comment: You beautiful genius! I am but a lowly fool. Thanks! That was it, so simple - only an idiot would have deliberately used `Int64` to represent a C++ `long`. Thanks again!